# Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to transform Data. This is my DataFrame (expense_overview)

|  | Expense | Proportion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Salaries | 0.62 |
| 1 | Advertising | 0.15 |
| 2 | Office Rent | 0.15 |
| 3 | Equipment | 0.03 |
| 4 | Utilities | 0.03 |
| 5 | Supples | 0.01 |
| 6 | Food | 0.01 |

I want to replace the values of the Expense variable that has corresponding values in Proportion variable that are less then 5% with the value "Other".

```
mask = expense_overview.isin(expense_overview[expense_overview["Proportion"] < 0.05]["Expense"])

expense_overview[mask] = "Other"
```

But I get the following Error:

Cannot do inplace boolean setting on "
TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this:

```
expense_overview.loc[expense_overview["Proportion"] < 0.05, "Expense"] = "Other"
```

Result:

```
       Expense  Proportion
0     Salaries        0.62
1  Advertising        0.15
2  Office Rent        0.15
3        Other        0.03
4        Other        0.03
5        Other        0.01
6        Other        0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas only solution:

```
expense_overview[lambda x: x.Proportion < 0.05] = expense_overview[lambda x: x.Proportion < 0.05].assign(Expense="Other")
```

Or using np.where:

```
expense_overview["Expense"] = np.where(expense_overview["Proportion"] < 0.05, "Other", expense_overview["Expense"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
mask = expense_overview*[„Expense“]*.isin(expense_overview[expense_overview["Proportion"] < 0.05]["Expense"])

expense_overview[mask, *„Expense“*] = "Other"
```